# toolbar not being displayed in tinymce text editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce, text-editor

I am using tinymce for the first time. I am following the example they have given but it doesn't seem to work. I can only see a text box with rounded corners, no toolbars and button.

What should I add to make it work properly? This is the code :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml11            /DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js" ></script >
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "emotions,spellchecker,advhr,insertdatetime,preview", 

    // Theme options - button# indicated the row# only
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,fontselect,fontsizeselect,formatselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,|,code,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "insertdate,inserttime,|,spellchecker,advhr,,removeformat,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions",      
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <form>  
    <textarea name="content" cols="50" rows="15" > 
    This is some content that will be editable with TinyMCE.
    </textarea>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check the images references?

Comment: no, do u mean this :- visual_table_class : "myCustomVisualAidTableClass"

Comment: No, I mean the paths to your images. Check that in your config file.

Comment: I am not able to find any config file. I have 4 folders lang, plugin,skin , theme and tinymce.min.js file

Comment: do you get any js-errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current download on the home page is version 4 which is still in beta. The docs and syntax in your question are for version 3.x. Version 4 is a major rewrite and much of the old syntax will no longer work.

You have three options:

- Download version 3.58 to use in conjunction with the docs.
  http://download.moxiecode.com/tinymce/3.5.8/tinymce_3.5.8.zip
- Figure out the new version on your own from demo, forum, and their fiddle.
  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/
- Wait for the stable release of version 4 since the docs will probably be fixed by then.

All you need to get started with version 4 is the selector:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea"
});
```

That will give you the default options with no plugins. If you look at the fiddle, you can see some of what you can do.